# Client devices randomly unenroll from Windows Hello for Business

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I have followed the Deployment Guide found here: [Windows Hello for Business Deployment Guide - On Premises Certificate Trust Deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-deployment-cert-trust)

We're able to set up fingerprint and facial recognition for the users and computers that are in the appropriate security groups, and when the screen is locked, the biometrics will unlock the computer. But after a few minutes (maybe 15 minutes, maybe an hour), Hello reverts back to an unenrolled state. No PIN, no fingerprints, no faces registered.

I've looked through the logs on the AD FS server, the CA server, and the client devices themselves, and I have no idea why the credentials are being deleted.

Anyone have any ideas on where to look?

Comment: 15 minutes sounds suspiciously like a Group Policy refresh time...

Comment: I've checked, and the policy is still in effect.

Comment: Check exactly what the GPO is doing. "15 minutes" is the refresh tiem, as @massimo said. Maybe it is re-setting your profile?